# How to remove a JavaFX ListView item when the user 'erases' it?

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a `ListView` with `TextField`-style cells.  (It's actually my own `ListCell`, which I poached and modified to implement per-keystroke validation.)

Sometimes, instead of clicking the nearby 'delete' button, a user will

1. start editing a cell
2. erase all of the text inside of it
3. commit the edit.

He will do all of this with the intent of trying to delete the item.  I'd like to support this use case if possible, but I do not know where to begin.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
list.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>()
{
    @Override
    public void handle( ListView.EditEvent<String> event )
    {
        String val = event.getNewValue();
        if ( val == null || val.trim().isEmpty() )
        {
            System.out.println( "removed = " + event.getSource().getItems().remove( event.getIndex() ) );
        }
    }
} );
```

Comment: will you clarify in what sense your solution "is not working as expected"?  I tested your solution with 8u11, 8u20, 8u25, 8u31, and 8u40 on both Linux and Windows and everything looked good to me.

Comment: @DavidCharles, the problem was in updateItem() of my testing code. Was incorrectly handling isEditing() logic flow. Updated.